# C# as Win Service cashes on Console.Title

Tags: c#, windows-services

I have a C# application which extends Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.AbstractionsBackgroundService. I use it to run other dlls as a Console app. On the later customer system this should run as a service. After two days of debbuging i realized, that

```
Console.Title = ...;
```

crashes it when running as a service. Does anyone else see this and has an explanation?

```
Console.WriteLine();
```

does not make any problems.

Comment: Windows services don't have a console.  I know there's someone out there who's going to say "well, actually," but Windows services are not meant to have any kind of screen output.

Comment: So "don't do that," basically.

Comment: Why would you want to do this?  You should be using event logging when doing windows services (you'll see essential services use this too).  If there was a service on my PC that tried to output something visually I would burn it with fire.

Comment: Yes i wont let this in my code. I added a switch which only applies when running as console app and not as a service. I was only suprised, that Console.Tile let my service crash. Because Console.WriteLine() is  discarded.